# Autogenerated DataGrid columns' sortability is random

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a DataGrid in WPF with autogenerated columns. Here's how it is declared in XAML:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Table}"
          IsReadOnly="True"
          EnableColumnVirtualization="True"
          EnableRowVirtualization="True"
          AutoGenerateColumns="True"/>
```

where `Table` is an `ObservableCollection` in the DataContext.

My problem is that the columns of the DataGrid are randomly deciding whether you can click on them to sort by that column or not. I'm not even touching the CanUserSort property. What may cause this?

Comment: can u put a sample of  your T obsevablecollection class ?

Comment: I strongly doubt that it is _random_.

Comment: @K.B The rowtype class is autogenerated by Entity Framework from the existing database.

Comment: @marczellm what do you mean by random? Sometimes one column is sortable and sometimes not or some columns are always sortable and some not?

Comment: @dkozl To me it seems the latter.

Comment: @marczellm then you need to show your EF model class, mainly types of properties and show which properties are not sortable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that for a DataGrid column to be sortable, its type

- cannot be `Nullable`, and
- has to have an ordering defined (built-in or `IComparable`, I guess).

So for example

```
public class Example {

    public long Id { get; set; } // sortable

    public Nullable<long> Id2 { get; set; } // not sortable

    public SomeOwnClass Ref { get; set; } // not sortable

}
```